# Unity 3d (Landscape with autorotate) in Ios 8 (Portrait and landscape)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode8

I have integrated a unity 3d content in a existing IOS app (xcode 8) and works correctly.

The Unity 3d content has autorotation and allow Landscape Right/Left.
The Ios project allow portrait and landscape.

When the ios app runs in iphone portrait (and load unity in appdelegate) as unity mark landscape after a seconds the apps rotate to landscape.

I have looked in private functions unity export to ios but not lucky to disable the first autorotation.

Any help, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the rotations you want from here? I think you did not change those from player settings.[image]

Comment: yes, in unity the player settings allow landscape only (the content is landscape ready only). In the ios app the orientation allow (portrait and landscape). Actually when the unity content is show the view rotate to landscape (perfectly).